# A anotação @Form do RestEasy não funciona no Glassfish 4.1

Tags: java, glassfish, jax-rs, resteasy

Eu estou tentando fazer uma aplicação java web legada que é empacotada dentro de um EAR e que foi escrita para o JBoss 7 funcionar no Glassfish 4.1. **A aplicação não é construída com maven e nem com gradle** (então por favor, não poste respostas sobre dependências maven, e eu não posso *mavenizar* ou *gradleizar* esta aplicação no momento). As dependências dela são apenas um monte de JARs localizados em uma pasta `lib`.

Meu problema é que alguns métodos do JAX-RS têm parâmetros anotados com `org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.Form`. Mas a aplicação não declara nenhuma dependência nos pacotes do RestEasy, então eu acho que eles estavam em algum lugar dentro do JBoss ou talvez em algum classpath *endorsed*. Eu não tenho acesso ao JBoss original, e não dá para olhar lá e ver como era.

Ao remover os métodos que tem os parâmetros anotados com `@Form` e fazer o deploy, a parte do JAX-RS funciona. Entretanto, esses métodos são muito importantes para a aplicação e não podem ser removidos.

Eu tentei adicionar os seguintes JARs:

- `resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.13.Final.jar`
- `resteasy-atom-provider-3.0.13.Final.jar`
- `resteasy-cdi-3.0.13.Final.jar`
- `resteasy-crypto-3.0.13.Final.jar`
- `resteasy-jackson2-provider-3.0.13.Final.jar`
- `resteasy-jaxb-provider-3.0.13.Final.jar`
- `resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.13.Final.jar`
- `resteasy-jsapi-3.0.13.Final.jar`
- `resteasy-multipart-provider-3.0.13.Final.jar`
- `resteasy-servlet-initializer-3.0.13.Final.jar`
- `async-http-servlet-3.0-3.0.13.Final.jar`

O melhor que consegui até agora é isso:

```
Grave:   ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5954)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:6037)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5929)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.servlet.ResteasyServletInitializer.register(ResteasyServletInitializer.java:108)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.servlet.ResteasyServletInitializer.onStartup(ResteasyServletInitializer.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:6031)
    ... 51 more
```

Que dependências podem estar faltando? Eu ainda não consigo criar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável, mas pretendo trabalhar nisso se ninguém souber a resposta.

Por sinal, não sei se é importante, mas de qualquer forma: A aplicação era construída no Eclipse (não sei qual versão). Agora estou usando o Netbeans 8.0.2.

Se isso importa, os controllers do JAX-RS são mais ou menos assim (note que isso também é um EJB):

```java
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Path("/foo")
public class FooController {

    @PUT
    @Path("/bar")
    public Response someMethod(@Form SomeBean bean, @CookieParam("blahblah") String someCookieValue) throws SomeBusinessException {
        // ...
    }
}
```

<sup><sub>Postado também em https://stackoverflow.com/q/33375822/540552</sub></sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como a aplicação foi feita para Jboss, para rodar no glassfish não só a migração do serviço Rest será um desafio. Não é trivial rodar o Jersey no Jboss ou o Resteasy no Glassfish. Para realizar, vá passo a passo. O primeiro é fazer a aplicação rodar no Jboss 7. Depois construa um serviço Rest no Glassfish. Logo, tente migrar o código construído no Jboss para o Glassfish. Assim, você terá os serviços funcionando em cada servidor de aplicação e poderá compará-los para verificar se é possível uma migração mais rápida para outros serviços do mesmo tipo.